# How to get currently viewed message in Outlook Inbox folder

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm writing an Application-Level Add-In for MS Outlook and now I need to determine what message is currently selected in Inbox folder (I mean the letter user is currently looking to). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, eventually I've found an answer, hope it will help somebody. Here it is:

```
                var explorer = _appOutlook.ActiveExplorer();
                if (explorer.Selection.Count > 0)
                {
                    var sel = explorer.Selection[1];
                    if (sel is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        var item = sel as MSOutlook.MailItem;
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected letter: "+item.Body);
                    }
                }
```